# Xamarin. Как запретить приложению вообще менять ориентирование при повороте экрана?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

Как запретить приложению вообще менять ориентирование при повороте экрана, даже если у пользователя "Поворот экрана" включен?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android - добавьте атрибут к Activity.
[Android(ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]

iOS - можете в настройке iOS проекта выбрать доступные ориентации экрана.